# Is there any harm in using NPM and Yarn in the same project?

Tags: yarnpkg

I have been using npm for a personal project and just recently stumbled across yarn. Would there be any harm or "intended side effects" to switching to yarn's package manager in the same project where I had been using npm?

Comment: I use both and prefer yarn (for speed) so if you can't mix and match the commands `npm install --save proj1` then later `yarn add proj2` then I need to know.  I believe you can mix-and-match, but I've definitely run into issues (when one of them complains) and I have deleted the node_modules directory and rebuilt it to fix the problem.  I understand that the lock files are different.  Good question!

Comment: In my project, I have used both npm and yarn. For example, one of the modules did not install properly with npm, so I used yarn to install that module. For many other I used npm. All in the same project. So far no problems..

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Although a few commenters here say its ok to mix both yarn and npm on the same project, after using yarn and npm and then yarn again, this is what yarn has to say about it:

```
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools
other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution 
inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove
package-lock.json.
```

Comment: yeah same to me.

Comment: But should I also remove `node_modules` and reinstall all the packages with `yarn install` ?

Comment: Too bad it's only a warning and not a full stop. There are developers who keep forgetting that we use `npm` and keep pushing `yarn.lock` into the repository.

Comment: @Qwerty this is the fault of `git add .`

Answer (score 12):

Since to me it is not any harm to using both them into one project.

I use npm and yarn (50/50) in dev environment.
But on ci/di i use only yarn because it is faster, and i reduce build minutes thanks yarn.

Also they both create different .lock file names.

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody!

Comment: on ci you can also use $ npm ci command; since npm ships with node it might me easier just to use npm for ci. https://blog.npmjs.org/post/171556855892/introducing-npm-ci-for-faster-more-reliable

Answer (score 7):

**Nobody told about the lock files.**

Imagine you use yarn on dev environment, and yarn on your build/production servers. When you install a package using yarn, and your project works on your computer, you probably would want to keep it working on a production environment (your server).

That being sad, you would commit you yarn.lock file, that "saves" the exact versions of each package you have, when the project ran on your computer.

On your buid/production server you should call `yarn install`, but asking to keep all the same versions with `--frozen-lockfile` parameter. Some even say ["`yarn install --frozen-lockfile` should be the default behavior"](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4147), and I agree.

Then... another dev jump in the project you are working and install a package using `npm` (other than `yarn`). That new package will not be included in your `yarn.lock` file, but, a new `package-json.lock` file would be created, telling the exact packages versions it is using.

When that commit arrives on your build/production server, it will crash, fail, because that new package doesn't exist on `yarn.lock` file. Someone would need to pull that changes, call a `yarn` to install the dependences and update the lock file with the new package dependences, and push it again to the repo.

---

A quick point about using the lock file or not. If you call a 'yarn install' on your build/production server some weeks after the last install on your machine, the server would have many other new versions than your last "stable" version. It already happened to me many times.

I published recently the [package-locks-checks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-locks-checks), which help ensure you have not just one lock file but also locked each package version on your project.

Comment: IMPORTANT !!! Read the above answer! In two words if you use both... you won't be able to host your website. I tried already to `netlify` and to `Heroku` and they give me the same warning and then deployment fails because of the warnings. They say to delete the `package-lock.json` file and then if I do, and try again they say the above file is missing, but you have dependencies with npm... Now what ??? :(

Comment: Hi, is there a way to check which packages are with `yarn` and uninstall them and install them with `npm`? I can't find anything. I tried `yarn check` and `npm ls` but they both yield errors. Or is there some other solution. Thanks

Comment: UPVOTE!!! I tried to deploy next.js app on both vercel and netlify, and I spent half a day to fix the issue described by you. If only I found this answer first lol

Answer (score 3):

Here https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/ we may find a confirmation that Yarn's resolution algorithm is compatible with NPM resolution algorithm.

Inside a npm project (with package.json) if you run `yarn` it will read your `node_modules` folder (using the resolution algorithm) and create a `yarn.lock` file with your project's locked dependency tree.

Based on that I assume that they are compatible inside the same project.

**Update 30/04/2021**

My original reply refers to `yarn 1 (classic)`, although I've just created a React app with `create-react-app` tool and it creates the project's repository with `package.json` + `yarn.lock` by default. Again, another demonstration that it's fine (even with the warning mentioned by Dave Pile).

At the end of the day this is a matter of putting both together to work and checking yourself...

Answer (score 3):

There will be a point that one or both will no longer work and your project will be stuck at only using the existing lock file. Meaning, the issue probably will involve installation fails if you opt to reinstall without a lock file. And that also means failure to create a new lock file, so you are stuck with the existing one that you are trying to get rid off in the first place. We are actually encountering this issue in one of our projects. Because it is so big, no one tries to fix the issue and just rely on the existing lock file.

So, even if we say it's a rare case that it won't cause harm. Mixing npm and yarn should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

When you mix NPM (Node Package Manager) and Yarn, both of which are package managers for JavaScript, several things can happen:

**Dependency conflicts**: NPM and Yarn use different lock file formats to manage dependencies. If you use NPM to install packages and then use Yarn to install or update packages, it can lead to conflicts between the lock files. This can result in unexpected behavior or version mismatches when running your application.

**Duplicate packages:** NPM and Yarn maintain separate caches for downloaded packages. If you switch between the two package managers, you may end up with duplicate copies of the same package in different cache directories. This can waste disk space and cause confusion if different versions of the same package are used.

**Performance issues:** Switching between NPM and Yarn can potentially slow down your development process. Each package manager has its own way of resolving dependencies and fetching packages, so constantly switching between them can impact build times and overall development speed.

**Inconsistent behavior:** NPM and Yarn may have slightly different behaviors and features, such as how they handle scripts or resolve package versions. Mixing them can lead to inconsistencies in how your project behaves, making it harder to debug issues or maintain a consistent development environment.

To avoid these problems, it's generally recommended to stick with one package manager throughout your project. Choose either NPM or Yarn and use it consistently for installing, updating, and managing your project dependencies. If you're working on a project that already uses one package manager, it's best to continue using that package manager to maintain consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Plus you get a warning from `yarn` as Dave Pile said because we have to push `*-lock.json` files changes you have to consider [using npm version >= 7](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/621733939456933888/npm-v7-series-why-keep-package-lockjson.html#:%7E:text=If%20packages%20are%20added%20or,and%20if%20a%20package%2Dlock.) to make sure whenever you install packages by `npm` it will update your `yarn-lock.json` file too.

Because whenever you install the packages either by `npm` or `yarn` depends on what you have chosen for updating a dependency in the `package.json` (Using tilde ( ~ ) which gives you bug fix releases and caret ( ^ ) gives you backward-compatible new functionality) it will update you`.lock` file and since you have to push it might happen that you have different version of lock files.