# Unable to import a library component that exists in node_modules folder

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I've installed 'react-image-gallery' library using yarn

```
yarn add react-image-gallery
```

And it now exists in my node_modules folder, but it says "Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-image-gallery'." when I try to import it.

How can I make it importable ?

[image]

Comment: are you doing it in exact same folder that it is installed ?

Comment: did you try what your `termial` is suggesting :
`npm i --save-dev @types/react-image-gallery` ?

Comment: @Codenewbie No. The directory of the picture is node_modules, and I'm trying to use it in src folder.

Comment: @OmarDieh I've installed this library with yarn and is it okay to use npm together ?

Comment: I wish to use this library without using npm, if possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589493/is-there-any-harm-in-using-npm-and-yarn-in-the-same-project

Comment: @Flippingflop as I was just reading now from this stack overflow [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589493/is-there-any-harm-in-using-npm-and-yarn-in-the-same-project), you are right, it is not recommended to mix npm and yarn packages together.  maybe you can try `yarn add @types/react-image-gallery` or `yarn add --dev @types/react-image-gallery` ?

Comment: @OmarDieh `yarn add @types/react-image-gallery` worked. thanks. Is `@types` making typescript to recognize this library ?

Comment: @Flippingflop Happy it worked ! I have posted my comments as an answer to help in similar future cases, I also explained why `@types` sometimes is useful. Since your issue was related to TypeScript you can also tag your question as TypeScript since it is not only a react issue. thank you too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using some third-party `packages` as `dependencies`, not all of those `packages` are written in `TypeScript`. Therefore the packages developers provide also an installation for the `type declarations` if other developers want to use those `types` in their `TypeScript` projects.
**In your case** to install the package `react-image-gallery` :

1. first `yarn add react-image-gallery`
2. then (when usinig TypeScript) `yarn add @types/react-image-gallery`

If you want to know more about `Type Declarations` check this official [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html)