# Several people on same project using different package manager?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, package-managers, pnpm

Let's say we have a Vue/React project that requires 3 people, but each of those people has a different taste in package manager.
The first person already feels cozy using npm, the second one uses yarn because he thinks it has better security, and the third person loves to use pnpm because he thinks it can save storage when having multiple projects.
Is it possible if that one project that is being worked on by those 3 people to run on each person's device using their chosen package manager?

Even if it is possible, is it something that is normal? Or is it something that we should avoid?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any harm in using NPM and Yarn in the same project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589493/is-there-any-harm-in-using-npm-and-yarn-in-the-same-project)

Comment: it's similar but, not exactly the same.
my question is based on the habit of my circle where we never push the lock files, neither package-log.json nor yarn.lock files.
so when we clone the project on our local pc, the project doesn't actually have a connection with any package manager.

Comment: that question you mention is about switching his own package manager inside his own device, so it will have 2 lock files in one project on one PC.
my question is about using different package manager in one project but on different PC, so one may only have package-lock.json, and the other just yarn.lock.

Comment: _"we never push the lock files"_ - well, there's your first problem.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for mentioning that.
I just realize the use of lock files after reading the answers to that question.
My previous team leader used to say not to push the lock files, because he say pushing the lock file often causes problems in the production server ci/cd.
So I assume that lock files are something that is not supposed to be pushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is something that you should avoid. Even if they used the same lockfile, there would be slight differences in how they work, so people would get "works on my machine" issues. You don't want to spend your time figuring out such issues.

Each project needs to pick one package manager and stick to a given major version of that package manager. You can even go one step further and stick to a given exact version of that package manager. That will make your setup most stable. You can use the new [packageManager](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packagemanager) field for that in `package.json`:

```
{
  "packageManager": "<package manager name>@<version>"
}
```

But you need to enable [corepack](https://nodejs.org/api/corepack.html) as it is an experimental feature of Node.js for now:

```
corepack enable
```

Comment: what is the different of that "packageManager" configuration with the "engines" configuration.?

Comment: when you use corepack, the specified version will be automatically downloaded and used when you run npm, pnpm, or yarn.